# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getColumn() on a non-object in propel-gen diff

Tags: propel

When I try to change the table structures using propel I am getting a Fatal error when I try to execute propel-gen diff. So how to resolve the issue?

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getColumn() on a non-object in /usr/share/php/data/propel_generator/lib/reverse/mysql/MysqlSchemaParser.php on line 329

Answer (score 0):

This happens when there's a parsing error in your schema.  You've probably changed something in your schema and that's now causing the failure.  Best you undo whatever change to the last valid schema, then try and re-apply your changes bit by bit and validate as you're making change.

It's difficult thought to point out the issue without your schema.